# I am facing a null pointer exception in findviewbyid function for kotlin(Android)

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception, logcat, findviewbyid

Logcat of Android studio states that "**Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: findViewById(R.id.rvMaps) must not be null**"

App installed on android emulator or physical device doesn't open up due to nullpointer
exception.

Been trying to find the solution from a few days but wasn't able to find on.

Help me out with this.
Thanks!

Code in MainActivity.kt is:

```
package eu.tutorials.mymaps

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity 

import android.os.Bundle

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

import eu.tutorials.mymaps.models.Place

import eu.tutorials.mymaps.models.UserMap

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var rvMaps: RecyclerView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    
        rvMaps = findViewById(R.id.rvMaps)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
        val userMaps = generateSampleData()
        // Set layout manager on the recycler view
        rvMaps.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        // Set adapter on the recycler view
        rvMaps.adapter = MapsAdapter(this, userMaps)
    }
    
    private fun generateSampleData(): List<UserMap> {
        return listOf(
            UserMap(
                "Memories from University",
                listOf(
                    Place("Branner Hall", "Best dorm at Stanford", 37.426, -122.163),
                    Place("Gates CS building", "Many long nights in this basement", 37.430, -122.173),
                    Place("Pinkberry", "First date with my wife", 37.444, -122.170)
                )
            ),
            UserMap("January vacation planning!",
                listOf(
                    Place("Tokyo", "Overnight layover", 35.67, 139.65),
                    Place("Ranchi", "Family visit + wedding!", 23.34, 85.31),
                    Place("Singapore", "Inspired by \"Crazy Rich Asians\"", 1.35, 103.82)
                )),
            UserMap("Singapore travel itinerary",
                listOf(
                    Place("Gardens by the Bay", "Amazing urban nature park", 1.282, 103.864),
                    Place("Jurong Bird Park", "Family-friendly park with many varieties of birds", 1.319, 103.706),
                    Place("Sentosa", "Island resort with panoramic views", 1.249, 103.830),
                    Place("Botanic Gardens", "One of the world's greatest tropical gardens", 1.3138, 103.8159)
                )
            ),
            UserMap("My favorite places in the Midwest",
                listOf(
                    Place("Chicago", "Urban center of the midwest, the \"Windy City\"", 41.878, -87.630),
                    Place("Rochester, Michigan", "The best of Detroit suburbia", 42.681, -83.134),
                    Place("Mackinaw City", "The entrance into the Upper Peninsula", 45.777, -84.727),
                    Place("Michigan State University", "Home to the Spartans", 42.701, -84.482),
                    Place("University of Michigan", "Home to the Wolverines", 42.278, -83.738)
                )
            ),
            UserMap("Restaurants to try",
                listOf(
                    Place("Champ's Diner", "Retro diner in Brooklyn", 40.709, -73.941),
                    Place("Althea", "Chicago upscale dining with an amazing view", 41.895, -87.625),
                    Place("Shizen", "Elegant sushi in San Francisco", 37.768, -122.422),
                    Place("Citizen Eatery", "Bright cafe in Austin with a pink rabbit", 30.322, -97.739),
                    Place("Kati Thai", "Authentic Portland Thai food, served with love", 45.505, -122.635)
                )
            )
        )
    }

}
```

I dont know the exact reason of this issue but I tried to access the rvMaps recycler view
through its id in the MainActivity.kt which threw a nullpointerexception crashing the app.

Comment: You should initialize this to   rvMaps = findViewById(R.id.rvMaps) below following lines.  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rvMaps = findViewById(R.id.rvMaps)
```

> write this code below

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

code

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    //rvMaps = findViewById(R.id.rvMaps) //you can't write here
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    rvMaps = findViewById(R.id.rvMaps) //it should be below setcontentview

    val userMaps = generateSampleData()
    // Set layout manager on the recycler view
    rvMaps.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    // Set adapter on the recycler view
    rvMaps.adapter = MapsAdapter(this, userMaps)
}
```

Comment: tysm!
It was damn simple!

Comment: @VibhorBhatt the reason it wasn't working is because `setContentView` tells the Activity what layout to display, and you can't lookup views (with `findViewById`) before the Activity is displaying any!